# Get Tweepy's response and send to a Django template

Tags: python, django, twitter, django-views, tweepy

I am trying to send the text of tweets (from tweepy) to a template in django 2.0 so I can display it in the browser. But every time I try to see if the browser has the tweets it acts as if there was nothing in the object I sent from the view.

I suspect the response from tweepy is in a different format from the expected in django generic views, but I don't know how to solve it if it's indeed that.

For context, you send a username from a simple form before the program searches for tweets for that username and collects them from the API (no errors here, I checked it through the manage.py shell and all the tweets are there in the model). Then, it sends that object to the template tweet_detail.html so it may appear.

I've just started learning Django, but the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial04/ don't have the answer.

Here's my URLs

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('tweet/search', views.search, name='search'),
    path('tweet/detail', views.TweetDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('tweet/collect', views.collect_tweets, name='collect_tweets'),
]
```

My Models

```
from django.db import models

class Tweet(models.Model):
    tweet_text = models.CharField(max_length=180)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet_text
```

My Views

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
import tweepy

from .models import Tweet

def collect_tweets(request):
    try:
        CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx'
        CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx'

        ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxx'
        ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxx'

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=request.POST.get('user_name'), count=5, tweet_mode="extended")

        for tweet in tweets [:5]:
            t = Tweet(tweet_text=tweet.full_text)
            t.save()

        return render(request, 'polls/tweet_detail.html')
    except KeyError:
        return render(request, 'polls/tweet_detail.html')

def search(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/tweet.html')

class TweetDetailView(generic.ListView):
    template_name= 'polls/tweet_detail.html'
    context_object_name= 'tweets'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tweet.objects.all()
```

The template to send the username for collection (tweet.html)

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:collect_tweets' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="1">Username: </label><br />
    <input name="user_name" id="1"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And the template for showing the results (tweet_detail.html)

```
{% if tweets %}
    <ul>
    {% for tweet in tweets %}
        <li> {{ tweet }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No tweets</p> <!--It always displays this-->
{% endif %}
```

I know there are probably a lot of broken rules for coding in django here, but the main concern is the result:

No tweets

But when I check the manage.py shell:

```
>>> from polls.models import Tweet
>>> Tweet.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Tweet: There is the correct text here>, <Tweet: And also here>]>
```

Could someone help?

UPDATE: if I change the search at the view from...

```
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=request.POST.get('user_name'), count=5, tweet_mode="extended")
```

to...

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=request.POST.get('user_name'), count=100).items(5)
```

It works, but using the user_timeline is preferable to my situation than Cursor